# Run an nstimer to show an ad ,but only show up on certain view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

This works out great, but I need it to show up in a certain class name "food" and no other class.Any tips will be appreciated.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

  //    [Shared instance];

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(ad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   }




      -(void)ad{
[ALInterstitialAd showOver:self.window];  
      }
```

Comment: Why not put the code in that view controller? Start the timer in viewDidAppear, and invalidate it in viewDidDisappear.

Comment: Perhaps subclass UIViewController and add the code as mentioned by @rdelmar? Then you can inherit from this class in the view controllers that need to display the ads and inherit directly from UIViewController in the ones that shouldn't display ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need to show it in a certain class, the do it in that class. You can use `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` to instantiate the `NSTimer`.